# Android showing an animation on opening an application and sending intent to main class on finish

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation

I want to make an application that shows a frame by frame animation when starting up. After the animation finishes, I want to send an intent to the main class (ReminderListActivity). However I can't seem to find how I define when the animation finishes.

Here's the relevant code:
The Animation class;

```
public class LoadActivity extends Activity {

AnimationDrawable animation;
long endTimeMillis;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.load_animation);

       startAnimation();

}

class Starter implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
           animation.start();
       }
   }

   private void startAnimation(){
       animation = new AnimationDrawable();

           animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dude1), 75);
           //....
           animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dude10), 75);

       animation.setOneShot(true);

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

       imageView.setImageDrawable(animation);
       imageView.post(new Starter());

       Intent i = new Intent(LoadActivity.this, ReminderListActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);

   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to register a listener to be called when the one-shot animation ends. As a work-around as you already know the duration of the animation, you may start the activity after the known delay:

```
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    Intent i = new Intent(LoadActivity.this, ReminderListActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}, 75 + 75);
```

Comment: Implemented it like this:

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
              Intent i = new Intent(LoadActivity.this, ReminderListActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);            
             }
        }, 2600);

And it works like a charm! thanks!